# How do I populate a Report Data Extension from 3 source Data Extensions in Marketing Cloud?

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions

I want to take the Record numbers in the 3 Source Data Extensions and add to the Report Data Extension. Then run a report on the Report Data Extension.

Comment: What is the report data extension? We will need more explanation to help you. Depending on the desired level of detail you can either use filters or query activity

Comment: What I've done previously is take the count of rows of multiple DEs and inserted those as records into a "governance" table (just a DE), so that we could see the trend in numbers across unsubs, subs, engagers etc. - but that required a manual look. Haven't seen anything about a report data extension? (please elaborate)